# Which microphone is compatible with Mac mini?

Tags: mac-mini

I searched a lot and I am still in doubt about which microphone to use in MC815BZA Apple Mac mini with Inte Core i5 2.3GHz, 2GB, 500GB HD, HDMI and Bluetooth.

What microphone will work with this computer?  I prefer to use Audio line out / headphone minijack (digital / analog) than USB 2.0 port.

Answer (score 2):

I have an older mac mini (2009) - and practically everything works out of the box. (and even some mics show up that I wouldn't even have guessed)

Tested:

- line in (no name)
- iPhone Headset through headphone plug
- Logitech USB Micro
- Samsung Bluetooth headset.
- Mic of Sony Camcorder through Firewire

So more likely than not - all you get will work.

Suppose there might be troubles with professional audio equipment - but these should have good enough support to find out for you.